# How to determine which model is connected to a treeview given a callback?

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

In Gtk 2.0 the cell toggled event, for example, passes the cell rendered and the path to the callback. But in order to change the underlying model data I need to know which treeview or which model this event is for. What is the proper way to determine that?

EDIT:

To clarify, the `GtkCellRenderer` *toggled* signal calls a callback with 3 parameters: `*cell_renderer`, `*path`, `user_data`. In this callback, how do I retrieve the model that is connected to the treeview that received this signal?

Comment: Could you please make clearer which signal of which class' callback are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect the "toggled" signal, you can pass the GtkTreeView or the model as the user_data. I'm not an expert on Gtk+ with C programming language :), but I guess the following code will help you:

```
void cb_toggled (GtkCellRendererToggle *cell_renderer,gchar *path, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkListStore *store = (GtkListStore *) user_data;
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(cell_renderer), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(cb_toggled), (gpointer)gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview));
    ...
}
```